# Redirect component from App Component and hide app component html

Tags: angular

I have written login code in app.components.html, but when I am logged in that page is still showing and redirection page is also showing. How to solve this problem in angular2? I want to show only the redirection page.

Comment: Can we see what your code is?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There could be many reasons for this, the most common is a syntax error. Are there any messages in the console? If the console does not have an error, then it may be an error in your code ... but you'll need to include some of that code in your post for us to help you.

Comment: My guess is that your app component contains the login page and router-outlet.  This router outlet is the insertion point for the current page, so if you've written the login page in the same file then it will always be shown.  If you move the login page to the component for the login route then it will solve the issue